# Motion detection on live streaming with react-native-webrtc

Tags: react-native, webrtc, image-recognition, motion-detection, react-native-camera

can you guys please help me with the react-native-webrtc. I have done security camera applications like Alfred using react-native-webrtc it's working fine. I'm getting difficult to get the motion detection on live streaming because of I can't able to get the frame on `<RTCView streamURL={this.state.videoURL} />`

I tried with react-native-camera and react-native-tensorflow it's detecting the image but I can't able to do live streaming using webrtc URL

I expected the output live streaming should work along with person/object detection, but the actual output live to stream works alone perfectly

Comment: Have you got anywhere with this? Im also looking to solve this

Comment: No. I didn't try because the project was stopped. If you get the solution please let me know because I personally need it. Thanks